# Clear Sorting HTML table in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sorting, angularjs-directive

Am displaying table without sorting. If click on column its sorting ascending and if i click again its sorting descending. Its working perfectly, but my requirement is if I click one more then its need to set normal(i.e., without sorting).

Am using `ng-repeat` with `order by` for sorting the table.
Here is the sample code

```
<tbody>
<tr class="table-tr" 
    data-ng-repeat="row in options.data | orderBy: features.sortField">
<td class="table-td" data-ng-repeat="column in options.fields">
        {{row[column['field']]}}
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do would be just add a reset button instead of keeping track of how many times in a row they clicked on a table heading.

I created a plunker that does both a reset button and tracks number of clicks to reset the sort predicate:

```
$scope.predicate = '';
```

I would clean up this code. I just wanted to get the idea across. http://plnkr.co/edit/vcvOf4vWgxTegi61GLxR?p=preview